# Primary Key Constraint Violation in SSIS with Quotation Mark

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Using SSIS Data Flow Task to transfer records from table in 1 SQL Server database to an IDENTICAL table in another SQL Server (2012) and getting "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'FLG_APVN_KEY_0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FLG_APVN'. The duplicate key value is ("ARIZ0010   ).".
In the Source table (FLG_APVN), there are two records with the following Primary Key values:   "ARIZ0010    and    ARIZ0010
Obviously similar but definitely distinct. The quotation mark at the beginning of the first PK Value seems to be getting dropped off by SSIS in the insert causing a primary key violation. I need both records in the destination table with their primary keys intact. How do I do this? (SQL Server 2012, SSIS from Visual Studio 2012).

Comment: Can you describe the Data Flow Task?  What type of Source, Destination etc?

Comment: Can you update on of them and after moving update again and roll it back?

Comment: Thanks guys. While doing some more digging I determined that a previous step in the SSIS Package wasn't clearing the table of the correct records before attempting to re-write them back into the table. Tough to notice on a table with hundreds of thousands of records!!! Anyway, it's working now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. See Comment above. Turns out that the quotation mark wasn't the problem.